# Django test cases: Not able to call execute function from GraphQL Client

Tags: python, django, graphene-python, django-tests, graphene-django

i am creating test cases to validate graphql api calls using graphene-django library and while trying to execute query i am getting Client obj has no attr execute where as the dir method is showing execute method, i am very confused any help is much appreciated:

here is what i have tried:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from graphene.test import Client

from app.graphql.schema import schema
from app.graphql.tests import constants


def generate_token(user):
    from app.serializers import TwoFactorAuthenticationSerializer
    return TwoFactorAuthenticationSerializer().get_token(user).access_token

class AssetGraphQLTestCase(TestCase):

    client = Client(schema)
    print("outside------------------", type(client))
    print("outside------------------", dir(client))

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        print("Setting up test data-------------------------------")
        cls.client = Client(schema)
        cls.user = constants.TEST_USER
        cls.organization = constants.TEST_ORGANIZATION
        cls.asset_1 = constants.TEST_ASSET_1
        cls.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION":generate_token(cls.user)
        }

        print("--------------------------------",type(cls.client))
        print("--------------------------------",dir(cls.client))


    def test_all_asset(self):
        print("Testing-------------------------------------------")
        response_data = self.client.execute(query=constants.GRAPHQL_ASSET_QUERY, varaibles=constants.QUERY_VARIABLES, headers=self.headers)
        print(response_data)
        print(response_data['data'])
        self.assertEqual(response_data.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response_data['data'], 'Expected value')`
```

here is the output:

```
Setting up test data-------------------------------
-------------------------------- <class 'graphene.test.Client'>
-------------------------------- ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'execute', 'execute_async', 'execute_options', 'format_error', 'format_result', 'schema']
Testing-------------------------------------------
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_all_asset (app.graphql.tests.test_assets_graphql_fix.AssetGraphQLTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/graphql/tests/test_assets_graphql_fix.py", line 41, in test_all_asset
    response_data = self.client.execute(query=constants.GRAPHQL_ASSET_QUERY, varaibles=constants.QUERY_VARIABLES, headers=self.headers)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'execute'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.009s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
root@b026e124367f:/app#
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting from `TestCase` which uses its client variable rather than the class variable you have defined and this `client` variable doesn't have `execute` method.

You can simply call your client class variable in `test_all_asset` method like this `AssetGraphQLTestCase.client.execute(..)`

I would recommend inheriting from `GraphQLTestCase` than django `TestCase`
here is the [example](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/testing/)